# Given $a+b+c+d=4$, find the minimum value of $\Sigma_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^3+4}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given $a+b+c+d=4$, find the minimum value of $\Sigma_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^3+4}$
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with Holder's inequality, but I don't know how to solve this. By guessing I found $a=2,b=2,c=d=0$ the smallest solution with $\Sigma_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^3+4}=\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not exist. Try $a>0$,$c>0$, $d>0$ and $b\rightarrow-\sqrt[3]4^-.$

For positive variables by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^3+4}=1+\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b^3+4}-\frac{a}{4}\right)=1+\sum_{cyc}\frac{-ab^3}{4(b^3+4)}=$$
$$=1+\sum_{cyc}\frac{-ab^3}{2(b^3+b^3+8)}\geq1+\sum_{cyc}\frac{-ab^3}{2\cdot3\sqrt[3]{b^6\cdot8}}=1-\frac{1}{12}\sum_{cyc}ab=$$
$$=1-\frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{12}\geq1-\frac{\left(\frac{a+c+b+d}{2}\right)^2}{12}=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I think $a,b,c,d>0$ Also can you find the maximum value of $\Sigma_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^3+4}$?

Comment: @Kai Yes I think I can. Open another topic for this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Didn't see your comment.